# TFS2010: Single Server Deployment wizard, Bad sharepoint URLs

Tags: sharepoint

I just installed TFS2010, and set it up with the single server wizard. It installed me Sharepoint Services an let everything working pretty well.

But, the sharepoint URLs it generates from the Server name "server". As my setup is without a domain, the URLs work okay only from the server computer, not from the others.

I have to give access to LAN clients, and Internet Clients, both connected thought my Public Ip.

How can I change those sharepoint IPs from TFS to be generated From the IP, not from the Server's name??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint is simply an ASP.Net web application sitting on IIS so all the configuration for host headers etc can be added in IIS itself - if you have multiple instance of sharepoint running on the server, you'll have to add URL's using the sharepoint configuration site but most stuff can be tweaked through IIS (IP's its listening on etc)

If you not on an domainan and want people to have access to the site though you'll have to add your machines IP to the DNS server that you clients are using

Comment: Yes but, the issue is that TFS shows on the Web Access Page, a link to a "Project Portal", with the URL as this: http://server/ProjectName
I need it to be: http://someIP/projectName

Comment: This can be changed in the TFS Administration once its setup.
Open TFSAC then click on "sharepoint web applications" select your web app and click "change" then change the hostnames to your servers IP instead. Easy fix :)